# Citing a Paper from Collected Works

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to cite a paper that I found in the *Collected Works* of an author. I cannot access the original, so a stand-alone bibliography entry not mentioning the *Collected Works* would be inaccurate.

My main issue is that the year of the publication of the paper and the year of the publication of the book are not being clearly distinguished.

Below an example, where a hypothetical article ("Some Paper"), originally published in 1900 by Albert Einstein (in e.g. "Journal of Physics"), is included in a book ("Collected Works Vol. 1: The Early Years") edited by John Doe.

It would also be nice to be able to include additional information about the original publication—publisher, editors, journal ("Journal of Physics"), etc., rather than just the year—of the article found in the *Collected Works*.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@inbook{einstein1900,
    author = {Albert {Einstein}},
    title = {{Some Paper}},
    year = {1900},
    pages = {30 -- 40},
    crossref = {einstein2000collectedworks}}
@book{einstein2000collectedworks,
    author = {Albert {Einstein}},
    editor = {John {Doe}},
    title = {{Collected Works}},
    volume = {1},
    subtitle = {{The Early Years}},
    year = {2010},
    publisher = {Publisher}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{einstein1900} appears in \cite{einstein2000collectedworks}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `related` field and refer to the original paper

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{einstein1900,
  author      = {Albert Einstein},
  title       = {Some Paper},
  pages       = {30 -- 40},
  crossref    = {einstein2000collectedworks},
  related     = {einstein1900orig},
  relatedtype = {reprintof},
}
@book{einstein2000collectedworks,
  author    = {Albert Einstein},
  editor    = {John Doe},
  title     = {Collected Works},
  volume    = {1},
  subtitle  = {The Early Years},
  year      = {2010},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@article{einstein1900orig,
  author      = {Albert Einstein},
  title       = {Some Paper},
  year        = {1900},
  journal     = {Journal},
  volume      = {34},
  number      = {2},
  pages       = {45-62},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\autocite{einstein1900} appears in \autocite{einstein2000collectedworks}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Albert Einstein. “Some Paper”. In: Collected Works. The Early Years. Ed. by John Doe. Vol. 1. Publisher, 2010, pp. 30–40. Repr. of “Some Paper”. In: Journal 34.2 (1900), pp. 45–62.]

---

If you want to base the label on the original publication date you need to pass the `origdate` to the entry and modify the label template

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[strwidth=3,strside=left,ifnames=1]{labelname}
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=left]{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{origyear}
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{einstein1900,
  author      = {Albert Einstein},
  title       = {Some Paper},
  pages       = {30 -- 40},
  crossref    = {einstein2000collectedworks},
  origdate    = {1900},
  related     = {einstein1900orig},
  relatedtype = {reprintof},
}
@book{einstein2000collectedworks,
  author    = {Albert Einstein},
  editor    = {John Doe},
  title     = {Collected Works},
  volume    = {1},
  subtitle  = {The Early Years},
  year      = {2010},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@article{einstein1900orig,
  author      = {Albert Einstein},
  title       = {Some Paper},
  year        = {1900},
  journal     = {Journal},
  volume      = {34},
  number      = {2},
  pages       = {45-62},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\autocite{einstein1900} appears in \autocite{einstein2000collectedworks}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you so much! One small question though; is it possible to modify the citation labels so that [Ein10b] becomes [Ein00], i.e. references the original year of publication?

Comment: @steve That's also possible (see edit), but unfortunately requires some duplication of data.

Answer (score 5):

If there's only one reference to the collected-works piece, I think you're better off using the `@incollection` entry type for the main entry. That way, you can reduce, ever so slightly, the amount of clutter in the body of the document, since you'll be generating just one citation call-out. If you feel it's helpful for your readers, your provide a `note` field to mention where and when the piece was published originally.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{references.bib}
@incollection{einstein1900,
    author    = {Albert {Einstein}},
    title     = {{Some Paper}},
    origyear  = {1900},
    pages     = {30--40},
    editor    = {John {Doe}},
    booktitle = {{Collected Works}},
    booksubtitle = {{The Early Years}},
    volume    = {1},
    year      = {2010},
    publisher = {Publisher},
    address   = {Some Place},
    note      = {(Originally published in 1905 in \emph{Annalen der Physik})},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex} % 'backend=biber' is the default
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{einstein1900} showed that \dots
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `note` field:

```
@inbook{einstein1900,
...
note = {Reprint of \emph{Journal of Physics} \textbf{45} (1900) 23--56.},
...
```

Comment: For this to work you need to know the citation style in advance though... aside from that a simple solution, thank you!